# Четные и нечетные числа

Tags: pascal

Здравствуйте, есть вопрос по одной задачке. Может, кто поможет решить?

> Задача: даны три целых числа `A, B, C`. Определить, есть ли среди них хотя бы одно четное и хотя бы одно нечетное. Числа `A, B, C`, не превышающие по модулю 10000. Формат выходных данных. Одна строка – "YES" или "NO".

```
program Main;
var
  a, b, c: longint;
begin
  readln(a, b, c);
  if (a < abs(10000)) or (b < abs(10000)) or (c < abs(10000)) then
  begin
  if (not odd(a) or not odd(b) or not odd(c)) then writeln('YES')  
  else if odd(a) or odd(b) or odd(c) then writeln('NO')
  end
  else writeln('input error!')
end.
```

Вот что у меня пока что получилось, решение в итоге оказалось частично верным (если верить системе тестов) :(

Ах да, есть ещё одна задача, которую я вообще не понимаю как решать:

> Дано число X. Требуется перевести это число в римскую систему счисления. Формат входного файла: Дано число X в десятичной системе счисления (1  ≤  X  ≤  100).
> Формат выходного файла: Выведите X в римской системе счисления.

Полностью решение писать не обязательно, я в принципе представляю, как надо решать (наверное, с помощью оператора `case`), но вот незадача, я совершенно не знаю римских цифр :(

Comment: Не превышающих 10000: `X <= 10000`. Вот и неверно.

Answer (score 4):

Либо перепишите условие в лоб, с перебором всех пар переменных, либо сократите:

```
if odd(a+b) and odd(a+c) and odd(b+c)) then writeln('NO')   
else writeln('YES')
```

Answer (score 4):

> но вот незадача, я совершенно не знаю римских цифр :(

Римские числа строятся из цифр I (1), V(5), X(10), L(50), C(100), D(500), M(1000)
Правила:
1) При записи цифр от большего к меньшему веса цифр суммируются

```
Пример: LXXVI = 76
```

2) При записи цифры с меньшим весом перед цифрой с большим весом вес первой (субтрактор) вычитается из веса второй

```
Пример: IX = 9
```

3) Два или более субтракторов подряд не допускаются

```
Пример: IIX = ошибка
```

4) При прочих равных выбирается более короткая запись

```
Пример: IX, а не VIIII
```

Существует масса модификаций правил (нет единого стандарта). Например, в некоторых системах правил допускается субтрактор из 5, 50, 500 (IV, XL), в некоторых - нет (IIII, XXXX). Вообще, большинство систем правил записи римских чисел сложились в Средневековье ;)

P.S. Хотел комментарием, а не ответом, но не уложился :)

Comment: Такое ощущение, что хешкод превращается в форум для двоешников и идиотов. Хотя что можно ожидать от современной системы образования?

Answer (score 1):

Вот исправил код, вроде работает:

```
program main;

var
  a, b, c: longint;
begin
  readln(a, b, c);
  if (a < abs(10000)) And (b < abs(10000)) And (c < abs(10000)) then
    begin
      If ((Odd(a) And (Not Odd(b) Or Not Odd(c))) Or
          (Odd(b) And (Not Odd(a) Or Not Odd(c))) Or
          (Odd(c) And (Not Odd(a) Or Not Odd(b)))) Then
            WriteLn('YES')
      Else
        WriteLn('NO');
    end
  else writeln('input error!');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Решение второй задачи, насколько я помню, можно найти в учебнике С. А. Немнюгина "Pascal Программирование на языке высокого уровня".

Comment: У Вас в условии проверяется, является ли хотя бы одно из чисел четным, а задние - одно четное и одно нечетное.

Comment: Да, я что-то невнимательно на задание посмотрел. Теперь исправил, работает как нужно.

Answer (score 1):

напиши по тупому:

сделай две переменные `k1`,`k2` - `k1` это будет количество нечетных, а `k2` 
количество четных.

Затем 3 if'a для проверки пример:

```
if (a mod 2=0) then k2:=k2+1
               else k1:=k1+1;
```

и так для `b` и `c` еще затем проверка:

```
if ((k1<>0) and (k2<>0)) then write('YES')
                         else write('NO');
```

и не забудь обнулить `k1` и `k2`.

Comment: Округлять-то зачем? Логичное продолжение - массив и цикл.

Comment: Остаточно одного счетчика, который проверяем на равенство 1 **или** 2 (тогда YES). 

Черт, вопросу уже полгода. Неактуально.

Comment: на паскале переменные в начале не округляются, а это может повлиять на ответ

Comment: > на паскале переменные в начале не округляются

Ничего не понял. Всё считается в поле целых чисел и округлять не имеет смысла.

Comment: блин. Я перепутал обнулить и округлить

Comment: А, вот оно что :-) Юзайте термин "инициализировать"